# Checkbox false to true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, forms

i have this checkbox in my form

```
     type="checkbox"
     value={wpp}
     name="wpp"
     onChange={(e) => setWpp(e.target.value)}
     />
```

and i defined like

`const [wpp, setWpp] = useState(false);`

how do I do when someone selects this checkbox to be sent to my database as true?

Comment: check if value='on' in your backend, which gets the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the checkbox you need to watch for the checked property

```
type="checkbox"
     checked={wpp}
     name="wpp"
     onChange={(e) => setWpp(e.target.checked)}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling setWpp onChange, you could create a function, in your component, like:

```
async function fetchRemote(){
    let newval = !wpp;
    // fetch remote server to send your new value
    setWpp(!wpp);
}
```

It should call your server, sending the opposite of actual "wpp".

Than in your code you should edit your

```
onChange={() => fetchRemote()}
```